# ember.js: Acceptance testing with an ajax request

Tags: ajax, ember.js, tdd, acceptance-testing, ember-cli-mirage

I'm writing an acceptance test where a user fills in a form and an ajax request is made to a third party resource. I'm mocking the request with [Ember CLI Mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/).

I'm writing a basic working example that I'll refactor after my tests pass. I know I need to abstract out my request into a service or utility but I don't like refactoring my code without a working test around it.

My code seems to work however, when I return a result that changes some content in the template, I can't get the test to pass.

It might be important to note: The third party API I am mocking out is not restful.

Here's the mirage config:

```
export default function() {
  this.post('/LogonAction', () => {
    return {foo: 'bar'};
  });
}
```

I haven't set the canonical URL of the web service yet. It should be an external service.

And my component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  result: null,
  errors: null,
  usernameTextChanged: function() { this.reset(); }.observes('username'),
  passwordTextChanged: function() { this.reset(); }.observes('password'),
  reset() {
    this.set('errors', null);
    this.set('result', null);
  },
  actions: {
    sync() {
      this.reset();

      // TODO abstract out validation and add more use cases
      if(this.get('username') === undefined || this.get('password') === undefined) {
        this.set('errors', 'Please fill out the form');
      }
      else {
        let params = { userId: this.get('username'), passwd: this.get('password') }

        this.set('test', 'foos'); //just checking...

        // TODO abstract out into a utility and move config values into config
        Ember.$.post('/LogonAction', params).then((r) => {
          // When I run tests, this renders to console.
          console.log('promise happened 1', r, this.get('result')); 
          // Fails here. I don't know why.
          this.set('result', true);
          // This does not execute
          console.log('promise happened 2', this.get('result'));
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You'll see that I output to console twice so I can debug it. I am not sure this is the right way to debug while I am writing tests.

This is my template:

```
<form id="logon" {{action 'sync' on='submit'}}>
  {{input value=username type="text" class="username" placeholder="Your username"}}
  {{input value=password type="password" class="password"}}
  <button>Click me</button>

  [[{{test}}]] <!-- this is just debugging -->

  {{#if result}}
    <div id="result">Sync complete</div>
  {{/if}}
  {{#if errors}}
    <div id="result">{{errors}}</div>
  {{/if}}
</form>
```

And finally, my test:

```
test('logging in', assert => {
  server.createList('LogonAction', 0);
  visit('/');

  console.log(0);

  fillIn('input.username', 'foo');
  fillIn('input.password', 'bar');
  click('button');

  console.log(1);

  andThen(() => {
    // The above console logs have happened.
    // It does not have the div#result tag in it!
    console.log(find('#logon').html());
    assert.equal(find('#result').text(), 'Sync complete'); // fails.
  });
});
```

The console logging (I think) tells me that the promise is resolved before I assert that the page shows the result to the user. But I can't get this to pass! As soon as I set the value of `result`, it fails.

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this might be related with the fact that run loop is disabled in testing mode. Nevertheless; I would have expected you to get the following error "Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in a run" but you say it fails silently. Can you give a try to the following: Just wrap the code `this.set('result', true);` within an `Ember.run` as follows:

```
    Ember.run(()=>{
      this.set('result', true);
    });
```

I do not have time to set up a twiddle to give a try to the code snippets; you have provided. Sorry for that; I would help more if you setup a twiddle and give feedback about the result of my answer. Good luck!

Comment: My apologies. The assertion actually works but when I log to console, that fails.

Comment: I guess I have misunderstood the question. It fails at `this.set('result', true);` line because a run loop is required; but does not exist since the environment is in testing mode. Hence; 'promise happened 2' is never rendered to the console due to error. Am I missing srh? This was what I was trying to explain. Sorry if I got it totally wrong.